# How to fix "Unqualified access" in delegates (qmllint warning)

Tags: qt, qml

I got the following DelegateModel

```
DelegateModel {
                id: visualModel
                model: columnModel

                delegate: TodoColumnDelegate {
                    todoColumnContentHeight: todosContainer.height - root.marginsSize*3
                    rootContainer: root
                    rootTodoContainer: todosContainer
                    todosColumnsViewPointerFromColumn: todosColumnsView
                    titlesAndTasksData: root.titlesAndTasksData
                    themeData: root.themeData
                    areTasksReversed: root.areTasksReversed
                    columnModelPointer: columnModel
                    taskModel: root.taskModelByColumnIDDict[columnID]
                }
            }
```

I want to pass those properties that are not part of the underlying model. They are mainly references to other properties.

qmllint throws the following warnings:

```
Warning: notes/src/qml/kanbanMain.qml:368:46: Unqualified access
                    todoColumnContentHeight: todosContainer.height - root.marginsSize*3
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Info: Did you mean "rootContainer"?
                    todoColumnContentHeight: rootContainer.height - root.marginsSize*3
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Warning: notes/src/qml/kanbanMain.qml:369:36: Unqualified access
                    rootContainer: root
```

etc...

What's the proper way of passing those delegates aliases (properties references) and other properties?

I tried making those properties "required" but they never get initialized when the delegates are created so it doesn't work.

Comment: It's hard to answer that without knowing where todosContainer comes from. A more complete example would be helpful. In general, unqualified access warnings can be fixed by specifying where exactly to find it. But if you're trying to reference something outside of the current file, I don't think qmllint is smart enough to know about it.

Comment: Hi @JarMan! The full code is available here: https://github.com/nuttyartist/notes/pull/574

todosContainer is inside the same file as the DelegateModel, but I guess the scope of delegates can't reach it?

Comment: The exact file in question: https://github.com/nuttyartist/notes/blob/f084f25fb4e67eaf6c47ad56342425fbde167345/src/qml/kanbanMain.qml

Comment: Does it work if you use `root.appBackgroundContainer.todosContainer`? Seems annoying to have to write all that out, but it shouldn't complain about being unqualified anymore with that.

Comment: It doesn't solve it. I also don't see why it would, `todosContainer` is not a property of `root`.